# preg_match and space at end

Tags: regex, preg-match, space

I have always battled to understand regex, but trying my hand at it anyway.
I got this problem...

```
$str_sql = "SELECT";
if(preg_match("/^(select|describe|pragma) /i", $str_sql)) { 
    print "match";
} else {
    print "no match";
}
```

This says "no match". However if I change it to :

```
$str_sql = "SELECT ";
```

This says "match". I tried with +$ / *$ / \b as well, but none seem to work.

Yes, you will never have case where your SQL just going to be that, but it also did not match with this... and this is more common in my code as i like to do it this way for readability...

```
$str_sql = "SELECT
column1, col2....
FROM table";
```

As soon as i put a space after SELECT, it matches. Not even the newline char in the above one triggers the match ?

Comment: The regexp has a space, so it only matches when there's a space in the string. What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks Barmar ... that was it. I feel so stupid now.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
if(preg_match("/^(select|describe|pragma)\b/i", $str_sql))
```

`\b` matches any word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of space use `\s` which matches any whitespace including `space, tab, new-line`:

```
preg_match("/^(select|describe|pragma)\s+/i"
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case you can do that:

```
if(preg_match("/^(select|describe|pragma).*$/", $str_sql))
```

the word can or can't include some other word, character or space, for example:

- "Select "
- "Select * from"
- "Select"

All will match. Also you can use:

if(p`reg_match("/^(select|describe|pragma)\s?$/", $str_sql))`

the word can or can't include only one space, tab or new-line.

I recommended you to use tools like RegexBuddy, it's so helpful, also you can review the RegexBuddy samples, they are interesting.

Good lucky, I hope this has been helpful.